# How to setup a setting whereby a user can select which type of alert they wish to display in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

I have a Firefox AddOn that displays various alerts. Is there a way in which I can setup the user being able to select which type of alert they wish to use? Currently I have two types of alerts. The standard JavaScript alert and a alertNotification. Is there a way of having a menuitem with the two different alerts the user can select. Not sure how I would code this in JavaScript though. The settings page is in XUL.

Code for both alerts currently:
    Code with both alerts:

```
if(resultEmail) {
               prompts.alert(null, "Test", "Email Address Detected");


  //Other form of alert. 
          var alertsService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/alerts-service;1"].
          getService(Components.interfaces.nsIAlertsService);
          alertsService.showAlertNotification("", 
                                "Test","Email Detected", 
                                false, "", null, ""); }
```

How can I setup that the user can choose between which alert they wish to use and have it setup in an XUL window? Not sure whether this is possible.

Currently have implemented this below now but still unable to get the user to choose which alert they wish to use.

Current Code to choose which alert:

```
var prefManager = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);
                var customAlert = prefManager.getBoolPref("extensions.yourextension.customalert");

        if(resultEmail) {
        if(!!customAlert)
                            {

                            // Show your alert
                             prompts.alert(null, "Privacy Exposure Detected", "Email Address Detected \n\nThis data is a privacy risk and should be reviewed");

                        } else {

                            // Show built in alert system
                            var alertsService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/alerts-service;1"].
                           getService(Components.interfaces.nsIAlertsService);
                            alertsService.showAlertNotification("chrome://spellchecker/content/images/stop.png", 
                                "Privacy Exposure Detected",vrs_getWin.document.getElementById(elementT).value+ "This data is a privacy risk", 
                                false, "", null, "");

                        }
```

XUL Window code:

```
<vbox>
        <hbox>
            <label control="custom-alert" value="Custom Alerts"/>
            <checkbox id="custom-alert" preference="customalert"/>
        </hbox>




            <button id="checkerOkButton" label="&savebutton.label;" oncommand="namespace_highlight.setPrefs();"/>
            <button id="checkerCancelButton" label="&cancelbutton.label;" oncommand="window.close();"/>
        </hbox>

    </vbox>
```

Issue is that the checkbox does not appear to be saving the input and it just defaults to the standard alert.

Any help will be grateful

Comment: What do you have in setPrefs()? If you look in about:config (carefully) you can see whether that boolean preference is being set or not. If not, you need to check the setPrefs function to see why

Comment: I currently have this in the setPrefs() setPrefs: function(){
   
            namespace_highlight.setbgColor();
            window.close();
        },

Comment: This is for another part of the AddOn.

Comment: What do I need to add in this setPrefs() function?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the choice of the drop down the user wants in a input element and query it before showing the alert. This can also be saved in a cookie for future remembrance of cross page support

```
//OR get type from session variable or cookie or whatever
var type = 1;
type = document.getElementById("userchoiceofalert").value;

function showAlert(type, subject, message)
{
if (type===1) {
    prompts.alert(null, subject, message);
} else {

  //Other form of alert. 
          var alertsService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/alerts-service;1"].
          getService(Components.interfaces.nsIAlertsService);
          alertsService.showAlertNotification("", 
                                subject,message, 
                                false, "", null, ""); 
    }
}

//in your function
if(resultEmail) {
showAlert(type,"Test", "Email Address Detected"); 
}
```

Comment: How would the user choose which alert they wished to use? Would I still need to attach this to a preference window in XUL?

Comment: Would it be defined in the prefWindow as userchoiceofalert?

Comment: how would I set this up in the prefwindow?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a prefwindow or some way to store your options already. So, you could create a preference for it using something like the following:

```
<label control="custom-alert" value="Custom Alerts"/>
<checkbox id="custom-alert" preference="customalert"/>
```

Then use the prefManager component to fetch the selected preference in your javascript:

```
var prefManager = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);
```

Will get you the prefManager service and from there you can check the value (in this case it's a boolean pref as we're using a checkbox:

```
var customAlert = prefManager.getBoolPref("extensions.yourextension.customalert");
```

Then where you are showing the alert type you would have:

```
if(!!customAlert)
{

    // Show your alert
    prompts.alert(null, "Test", "Email Address Detected");

} else {

    // Show built in alert system
    var alertsService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/alerts-service;1"]....

}
```

Just make sure that in your prefs.js file you have the preference setup such as:

```
// Default value for the preference
pref("extensions.yourextension.customalert", false);
```

Comment: Is this code part of the JavaScript where the If statement is or contained in the XUL Window Preference window? var prefManager = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);

Comment: Right have implemented the above but it only seems to default to the built in alert. It will not display the other alert.

Comment: I have the checkbox working but does not appear to save what the user chooses. I have edited the question above with the new details. Any help with this would be great.